# Import project from googlesource into Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to see how the [DeskClock](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/) works, but I can not figure out how to import that code into Android Studio 2.2.

I have git cloned it into a local folder, and when I start Studio and select the DeskClock folder with "Open an existing project with Android Studio" it shows up like this:
[image]

Can anyonw provide me a step by step guide on how to import this into Android Studio?

Comment: Those apps are not designed to be imported into Android Studio, or even built, outside of a full firmware build.

Comment: Pity. Thanks for the answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

You must used "Import project"  not "Open project"